# Typescript union/intersection types for functions

Tags: typescript, function, types

I am trying to understand how to specify a type (for a function) when I have varying numbers of parameters and return types.

This function can either:

- take 2 arguments (one is optional) and returns a Promise
- take 2 arguments (the second one is a callback)
- take 3 arguments (the third one is a callback)

Let's first define 3 types for the 3 cases:

```
type Func1 = (a: string, b?: number) => Promise<void>;
type Func2 = (a: string, b: () => void) => void;
type Func3 = (a: string, c: number, b: () => void) => void;
```

Now I would like to define a type that encompasses those 3. I read that you should use intersection for function types.

```
type MultiFunction = Func1 & Func2 & Func3;

const f1: MultiFunction = async (a: string, b: number) => {};
const f2: MultiFunction = (a: string, b: () => void) => {};
const f3: MultiFunction = (a: string, c: number, b: () => void) => {};

f1("foo", 3);
f2("foo", () => {});
f3("foo", 3, () => {});
```

But here a get errors on the declarations:

```
Type '(a: string, b: number) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'MultiFunction'.
  Type '(a: string, b: number) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Func2'.
    Types of parameters 'b' and 'b' are incompatible.
      Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)

const f1: MultiFunction
```

If I use union:

```
type MultiFunction = Func1 | Func2 | Func3;

const f1: MultiFunction = async (a: string, b: number) => {};
const f2: MultiFunction = (a: string, b: () => void) => {};
const f3: MultiFunction = (a: string, c: number, b: () => void) => {};

f1("foo", 3);
f2("foo", () => {});
f3("foo", 3, () => {});
```

I get an error on `f1("foo", 3);`:

```
Expected 3 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)

types_test.ts(3, 37): An argument for 'b' was not provided.
```

My question is, what is the correct way to handle this (and similar) case?

Answer (score 0):

Use [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) like this:

```js
function func(a: string, b?: number):Promise<void>;
function func(a: string, b: () => void): void;
function func(a: string, c: number, b: () => void): void
function func(a: string, b?: any, c?: any): any {

}

func("foo", 3);
// interpreted as
// function func(a: string, b?: number | undefined): Promise<void>

func("foo", () => {});
// interpreted as
// function func(a: string, b: () => void): void

func("foo", 3, () => {});
// interpreted as
// function func(a: string, c: number, b: () => void): void
```

TS Playground link: https://tsplay.dev/WoJnLm

Comment: That's interesting, but you get stuck with `func` as the name of the function. My intention was to provide a type so that I could create any number of functions with different names and different implementations but still with one of the provided signatures. As you might have noticed, the signatures are for the classic dichotomy "promise or callback" style of functions.

Comment: This is one way to implement "promise or callback" pattern. If I remember correctly, this is what I have seen in Mongoose. If you pass a callback, the callback is called and void is returned, if not a promise it returned. But I guess overloading is not what you wanted.

Comment: yes, function overload was not what I intended for my use case. I wanted to define a generic type (generic is not the correct term here, but anyway) that would cover these functions. I guess it is either impossible or it gets too messy.